# Angular Reactive Form Disabled Control is not valid

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I thought that a `disabled` control would not get validated. But I'm facing this issue.

I have reproduced using the official Angular reactive form sample:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyvj24?file=src/app/dynamic-form-question.component.ts

If you type something in the email field and focus out, this will trigger the `change` event in which I'm doing :

```js
this.form.controls['firstName'].disable();
```

[image]

And although, firstname is NOT a required field, it gets validated and we see a red message.
Without this line of code, firstName can be blank and we'll still be able to save.

Why is that ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<strike>When you disabled a control, the control will be valid or not, is the **form** which is valid although the control is invalid. e.g.</strike>

```
form=new FormGroup({
    control1:new FormControl({value:null,disabled:true},Validators.required),
    control2:new FormControl()
  })

{{form.valid}} //true
{{form.get('control1').valid}}  //false
```

In your particular case you can change the function isValid for some like:

```
get isValid() {  
   return this.form.controls[this.question.key].disabled || 
          !this.form.controls[this.question.key].invalid; 
}
```

**Updated** Sorry, my bad, in [the docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#status) we can see that status can be

- VALID
- INVALID
- PENDING
- DISABLED

a form control is valid when status is valid -so if status is disabled valid is false. We need use the "oposite" of invalid

```
get isValid() {  
   return !this.form.controls[this.question.key].invalid; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure i understand. You are saying that the form is valid, although my disabled control is invalid, right ?   But what I'm confused with is why my disabled control is invalid. Why the textbox, although it is not required, is invalid  ?  And if it is enabled, the validation passes, although there is no value.

Comment: sorry, @Sam, my answer was wrong, you need use invalid to check it

Comment: Perfect !  Thank you it works. I have to say this behavior is a bit strange though.

Comment: It may work but not right!!
The control is not checked at all when it is disabled because it has only one status and necessarily when it is disabled it is not valid/invalid/pending

Comment: What if a required field should not be user-editable but gets updated by another field based on the selection? Then how do we set the whole form as invalid if a disabled field becomes invalid? (The exact problem I am facing now)

Comment: Update: I guess I can just modify the function to iterate over the ".errors" attribute of the form's controls, and check if there are no errors for each form control... And avoid using ".invalid" entirely

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `.disable()` would not get validated. From the official Angular documentation:

> Disables the control. This means the control is exempt from validation checks and excluded from the aggregate value of any parent. Its status is DISABLED.
> If the control has children, all children are also disabled.

It is the check that is wrong. In the stackbiz it is:

> get isValid() {
> return this.form.controls[this.question.key].valid;
> }

while it should be:

```
  get isValid() {
    return this.form.valid;
  }
```